# Representing inequalties with proper boundaries

Tags: regions, inequalities, intervals

I have a very simple problem: given an inequality, I'd like to represent it in a regional plot marking the boundary differently depending whether it belongs to the region or not. For example I'd like to rappresent the region 1/2<=x^2+y^2<1 with a full line for the inner boundary and with a dashed line outside boundary. I'd like a function that does this automatically. I'm using Mathematica 9.
It's a pity that Mathematica doesn't seem to distinguish between open and closed intervals and has no automatic function to turn inequalities into intervals and, more in general, sets.